# Extending Windows security model

Tags: windows, security, winapi

Andrew S. Tanenbaum in its "Modern Operating Systems (4th Edition)" writes:

> Another area for which Win32 provides calls is security. Every thread is associated with a kernel-mode object, called a token, which provides information about the identity and privileges associated with the thread. Every object can have an ACL (Access Control List) telling in great detail precisely which users may access it and which operations they may perform on it. This approach provides for fine-grained security in which specific users can be allowed or denied specific access to every object. **The security model is extensible, allowing applications to add new security rules, such as limiting the hours access is permitted.**

How could something like this be done exactly? Where can I find more technical details about this topic?

Comment: You know how SO works! Show us something you have tried. As it stands, your question *could* be construed as off-topic, asking for recommendation of libraries, etc.

Comment: @Adrian I'm just trying to understand the meaning of the highlighted sentence. I didn't know that Windows provides any way to extend its security model like this. Now from this book I know this but it's still not clear how exactly it is possible.

Comment: I think the clue is in the preceding sentence: maybe read up on Access Control Lists, and come back to us when you've exhausted that line of enquiry?

Comment: The 4th edition was released in 2014, so this includes [dynamic access control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/solution-guides/dynamic-access-control-overview) (Windows 8, Server 2012) in addition to the user-mode Authz support for conditional/callback ACEs in Windows 7. A SACL can now include resource attributes and scoped-policy (i.e. applicable CAP) attributes. Access tokens are extended with user and device claim security attributes from kerberos authentication tickets. The kernel's access check now supports central access policies (CAPs) and conditional ACEs.

Comment: [\[MS-DTYP\] 2.4.4.17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/10dc22eb-788d-4343-b556-0b6969fe58ca) is a good overview of conditional ACEs. Section 2.5.1 covers them for SDDL strings, but they're explained better in [Security Descriptor Definition Language for Conditional ACEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptor-definition-language-for-conditional-aces-).